# Puppet script to schedule a cron after a job is completed

Tags: puppet

I am fairly new to puppet and thinking if there is a way to apply a resource only after the command initiated by Exec completes it's job. My requirement is that I should schedule a backup job only after another job is completed. My code, given below doesn't work. The cron gets scheduled as soon as the primary-backup-job is initiated.

Edit: I need to run primary job only once in life-time of the container(using docker). Primary backup job can take upto 5 hours and secondary around one hour. Primary-backup-script.py uses subprocess.popen module, to start the job , which forks the job in background, but I don't think that is important. Correct me if I am wrong.

```
exec{ 'primary-backup-job':
    command     => '/path/primary-backup-script.py',
    require     => File['/path/primary-backup-script.py'],
    refreshonly => true,
    }

# Schedule cron job only after primary backup is completed.
cron{ schedule-secondary-backup:
    command => "/path/secondary-backup-script.py",
    require => Exec['primary-backup-job'],
    user    => root,
    hour    => 05,
    minute  => 00,
    weekday => 1-5;
    }
```

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: I'd kick off the primary backup job in the back ground.  I'd use shell or python in the primary backup job to write a lock file.  The secondary job will check for the presence/ absence of the lock file before it starts running.  I would not use puppet for a job that lasts 5 hours